# Running Portfolio Performance

Tags: software-installation

the program does not start. I switched to Java 8 but it didn't work. Thanks for the help.

```
!SESSION 2021-01-30 23:21:09.470 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=unknown
java.version=1.8.0_275
java.vendor=Private Build
BootLoader constants: OS=linux, ARCH=x86_64, WS=gtk, NL=de_DE
Command-line arguments:  -os linux -ws gtk -arch x86_64

!ENTRY org.eclipse.e4.ui.bindings 4 0 2021-01-30 23:21:10.218
!MESSAGE FrameworkEvent ERROR
!STACK 0
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Could not resolve module: org.eclipse.e4.ui.bindings [160]
  Unresolved requirement: Import-Package: org.eclipse.e4.core.commands.internal
    -> Export-Package: org.eclipse.e4.core.commands.internal; bundle-symbolic-name="org.eclipse.e4.core.commands"; bundle-version="0.13.0.v20201119-1132"; version="0.0.0"; x-friends:="org.eclipse.e4.ui.bindings,org.eclipse.ui.workbench"
       org.eclipse.e4.core.commands [112]
         Unresolved requirement: Require-Capability: osgi.ee; filter:="(&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=11))"
  Unresolved requirement: Import-Package: org.eclipse.e4.core.commands
    -> Export-Package: org.eclipse.e4.core.commands; bundle-symbolic-name="org.eclipse.e4.core.commands"; bundle-version="0.13.0.v20201119-1132"; version="0.0.0"; x-friends:="org.eclipse.e4.ui.bindings,  org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench,  org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt,  org.eclipse.ui.workbench,  org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.swt,  org.eclipse.e4.ui.progress,  org.eclipse.e4.core.commands.tests"

    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.start(Module.java:463)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel$2.run(ModuleContainer.java:1845)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxContainerAdaptor$1$1.execute(EquinoxContainerAdaptor.java:136)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1838)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1779)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.doContainerStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1743)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1665)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:234)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:345)
```

Comment: The error message says the program requires Java 11: `Require-Capability: osgi.ee; filter:="(&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=11))` but your question says that you are currently using Java 8.

Comment: Thanks, that really worked. I thought I had Java 11 and read it required Java 8. Now I figured out I had Java 14 active.

Comment: I posted my last comment as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message says the program requires Java 11: `Require-Capability: osgi.ee; filter:="(&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=11))`, but your question says that you are currently using Java 8. To install Java 11 in Ubuntu 18.04 and later open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt install openjdk-11-jdk
```

You can have multiple Java versions installed alongside each other and set the default Java version with `update-java-alternatives`.

```
$ update-java-alternatives
usage: update-java-alternatives [--jre-headless] [--jre] [--plugin] [-v|--verbose]
           -l|--list [<jname>]
           -s|--set <jname>
           -a|--auto
           -h|-?|--help
```